# Facebook login only

Tags: users, social-network

I'd like to allow user register/login via Facebook only. After installing [Simple FB Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_fb_connect), there is a new `Facebook login` tag at: `user/simple-fb-connect`

[image]

The question is, how can I remove:

- Create new account
- Log in
- Request new password

tags from: `user/register`?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create custom `tpl.php` file of user registration
2. Comment the `$tabs` section or `$conten`t
3. Render facebook login form using form id and render it.
4. Another method is that use penals create a new page and add facebook login block in that page,Set page path on user login

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there's 2 ways to go about this.

One is to disable those tabs at the Drupal level. This can be done via `hook_menu_alter()` or for a solution that doesn't need custom code, use the [Tab Tamer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer).

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
>   hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab
>   labels.

The other way, is change your theme to hide those tabs via CSS (e.g. using a `display: none;` property). This way the URLs are still accessible to users that don't want to be forced to login via FB (e.g. admins).